# Add hand-wrapped method to Swig output

Tags: python, swig

I have a SWIG module where I want to add a hand-rolled method.

```
%module frob

%inline %{

    int Foo(int x, int y) { return x+y; }

    PyObject* Bar(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
        return PyString_FromString("Hello from Bar");
    }
%}
```

However, when I ran swig over it `swig -python frob.i`, I saw that SWIG actually wrapped both Foo and Bar as _wrap_Foo, _wrap_Bar.

```
 SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_Foo(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
   // ...
   result = (int)Foo(arg1,arg2);
   // ...
 }    
 SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_Bar(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
   // ...
   result = (PyObject *)Bar(arg1,arg2);
   // ... 
}
```

How do I tell SWIG to stop wrapping Bar for me, but just expose it in the PyMethodDef table?

Comment: I have no idea. However if you really get stuck, you can try using [cython](http://www.cython.org/)!

Comment: There's `%native` for SWIG+Java, but I'm not aware of an equivalent with Python. Is there a reason you need to do it like this given it goes into the intermediate module anyway and not the one that users of your module access directly? Your function gets passed through pretty sanely still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude a function from being wrapped, use the %native directive.

```
%module "test"

/* Prototype */    
%native(DontWrapMeBro)
PyObject* DontWrapMeBro(PyObject* self, PyObject* args);

%{
  PyObject* DontWrapMeBro(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
  {
    return PyString_AsString("Don't wrap me");
  }
%}
```

Comment: Oh nice - I assumed it was Java specific since that was the only part of the documentation I'd seen it mentioned in!