# How to add a hand-written CPython method to my SWIG wrapped class

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, swig

I have a C++ class that is wrapped for Python using SWIG -builtin. I'd like to add a method to that class that is wrapped in pure CPython, e.g., I want this in my methoddef list:

```
{ "handRolledCall", (PyCFunction) _wrap_MyClass_handRolledCall, METH_NOARGS, (char *) "" },
```

where I've defined `_wrap_MyClass_handRolledCall()`. I can get pretty close using %extend:

```
%extend MyClass {
     PyObject* handRolledCall(PyObject* arg1, PyObject* arg2) {
         // access the C++ value of self with $self
     }
}
```

But that always eats the Python PyObject value of `self`. This means there is no way to manipulate the Python state of the input object, for instance if I wanted to add it to a collection.

I've also tried using %native, as suggested in  [Add hand-wrapped method to Swig output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187658/add-hand-wrapped-method-to-swig-output). But that is about free functions, and doesn't provide a way to add methods to an existing class.

Because I'm using SWIG -builtin, I can't monkeypatch on the Python side. My use-case is generating Python `__enter__` methods for some classes that should act as context managers.

Comment: I can only think of some very kludgey ways to do this, other than subclassing the type you want to add it to

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm doing now, but that doesn't do a very good job for situations in which I have a function that returns one of these classes that should have an `__enter__` method.